# i want to show jquery variable data in stripe amount

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe and want to gert jquery vairable selected data as a stripe amount.

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                            data-key="<?php echo $publishable_key; ?>"
                            data-name="name"
                            data-description="testing"
                            data-image="test"
                            data-amount="<?php echo $plugin_price; ?>"
                            data-locale="auto"></script>
                    <?php /* you can pass parameters to php file in hidden fields, for example - plugin ID */ ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="plugin_id" value="<?php echo $plugin_id; ?>">
                </form>
```

my jquery code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $("#next_btn1").click(function () {
                                    var favorite = [];
                                    var second = [];
                                    $.each($("input[name='check_list[]']:checked"), function () {
                                        favorite.push($(this).val());
                                        second.push($(this).data('value1'));
                                        //$("#content").append("<tr><td>" + parseFloat(favorite).toFixed(1) + "</td><td>" + second+ "</td></tr>");

                                    });
                                    alert("data: " + favorite.join(", "));
                                    alert("data1: " + second.join(", "));

                                    $('#test1').text(favorite);

                                    $('#service').text(second);
                                    //$('#datavalue').html(favorite,second);


                                });
                            });

                        });
```

I want to get the checkbox data it has price and want this data to be in data-amount in stripe

i dont know how can  do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a variable amount to be displayed in Stripe's Checkout, you'll need to use their [custom Checkout integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), rather than the simple `data-amount` attribute.

See a full example here, https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/g2ufa8xr/

```
$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  // gets amount from a form input
  var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);

  // Open Checkout with further options
  handler.open({
    name: 'Demo Site',
    amount: amountInCents,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i am getting logs but i am not getting payments in stripe